# How to use map to lowercase strings in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I'm experimenting around with the use of `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` in Python 3.6 at the moment. What I'm trying to do is, given a ***list of dictionaries***, change all the values associated with a certain key to a lower-case value. For example:

```
message_one = {"content": "I'm glad I know sign language, it's pretty handy."}
message_two = {"content": "I am on a seafood diet. Every time I see food, I eat it."}
message_three = {"content": "Labyrinths are amazing."}
messages = [message_one , message_two , message_three]

print(to_lowercase(tweets))
#to_lowercase should just return the a list of dictionaries, but content lower-cased.
```

I attempted to use *map* at first.

```
def to_lowercase(messages):
    lower_case = map(lambda x: x["content"].lower(), messages)
    return lower_case
```

However, this just seems to return a list of all the content-messages in a list and does not perserve the dictionary format.
I don't believe `reduce` would be proper in this scenario because I'm not looking to return a single value at the end, and `filter` does not seem to make sense either here.

How would I use either `map`, `reduce`, or `filter` to achieve this job?

Comment: No, `reduce()` and `filter()` are not the right tools here. They'd do very different things. `filter()` is used to *select elements* from a list, and `reduce()` is used to produce an accumulation. Like a sum or a list or anything else that requires an intermediary result to be updated with the next element from the sequence. These are not the tools you are looking for.

Comment: Are there any other keys in the dictionaries that need preserving? Is updating the dictionaries *in place* acceptable, or must you produce copies?

Comment: Do you want to *change* the values in the existing dictionary, or do you want to return a *new* dictionary with the lowercase values?

Comment: If you want to *change* the input, you shouldn't use functional programming tools like `map`. If you want to build new dicts, `map` may be appropriate, though a comprehension or perhaps an explicit loop may be cleaner.

Comment: My apologizes for the ambiguity - it should return a new dictionary with the same key-value pairs; however, all the values should be lower-cased.

Comment: @DigitalVeer: and by 'all values' you mean there can be more keys? Are all values always strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note, this answer assumes you are using Python 2; if you are using Python 3 take into account that `map()` returns an *iterator* and you'd need to add a loop of some sort to see the results).

If you insist on using `map()`, then you want to create a new function to apply to each existing dictionary:

```
def dict_lowercase_content(d):
    """Produces a copy of `d` with the `content` key lowercased"""
    copy = dict(d)
    if 'content' in copy:
        copy['content'] = copy['content'].lower()
    return copy

def to_lowercase(tweets):
    return map(dict_lowercase_content, tweets)
```

The `dict_lowercase_content()` makes no assumptions about what keys are present in the dictionary; it'll create a shallow copy of *all* the keys, and *if* a `content` key is present it is lowercased.

Of course, if you can be certain that only the `content` key is important and always present, you could just create entirely new dictionaries with just that key;

```
def to_lowercase(tweets):
    return map(lambda d: {'content': d['content'].lower()}, tweets)
```

If updating dictionaries *in-place* is fine however (which would be more efficient), just use a loop:

```
def to_lowercase(tweets):
    for tweet in tweets:
        if 'content' in tweet:
            tweet['content'] = tweet['content'].lower()
```

Note that this function returns `None`! This is the Python convention; when altering mutable objects in-place, don't return those objects again as the caller already has a reference.

You can't use `reduce()` or `filter()` for this job.

- `filter()` *selects elements from the iterable*. You are not selecting, you are transforming.
- `reduce()` *aggregates elements*; each element from the input is passed to a function together with a running result; whatever the function returns is taken as the updated result. Think summing, or concatenating, or traversing a tree. Again, you are not aggregating, you are transforming.

Comment: I know you know :) but... when you print the result of `to_lowercase()` as OP does, you get `<map object at 0x0000000002xxxxxxx>` unless you're using python 2 or converting to `list`. That's why I don't use map much at the end of a chain (ok seeing the question, OP is clearly using python 2)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: the fact that they also are looking at reduce is a dead giveaway..

Comment: yes, I saw that too. Fortunately now `reduce` is "hidden" (buried?) in `functools` and noone ever has the idea of using it: you don't get extra points for using `reduce` !

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution to get a list of new dicts with *lowercased* values:

```
dicts = [{k:v.lower() for k,v in d.items()} for d in messages]
print(dicts)
```

The output:

```
[{'content': "i'm glad i know sign language, it's pretty handy."}, {'content': 'i am on a seafood diet. every time i see food, i eat it.'}, {'content': 'labyrinths are amazing.'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

With `map`:

```
map(lambda x: {'content': x['content'].lower()}, messages)
```

Without `map`:

```
[{'content': x['content'].lower()} for x in messages]
```

Without `map`, but more robust:

```
[{y: x[y].lower()} for x in messages for y in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

map() is a built-in higher order function that transform a collection.  We are supplying an anonymous function(lambda) for map to execute instead of providing the collection as an argument itself.  One way to achieve what you want would be:

```
transformed_messages = list(map(lambda x: {'content':x['content'].lower()}, messages))
```